# Rudin's theorem 7.29

Tags: analysis

In Rudin's POMA, the 7.29 theorem says:

> Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the uniform closure of an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of bounded functions. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a uniformly closed algebra.

I understand the part proving that $\mathcal{B}$ is an algebra but not that which is uniformly closed. Shouldn't we prove that there exist $(f_n) \in \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly ?

> Proof:
>
> If $f, g \in \mathcal{B}$ there exist uniformly convergent sequences $(f_n), (g_n)$ s.t. $f_n \rightarrow f$, $g_n \rightarrow g$, $f_n, g_n \in \mathcal{A}$. Since we are dealing with bounded functions, it is easy to show that:
>
> - $f_n + g_n \rightarrow f+g$
> - $f_n g_n \rightarrow fg$
> - $c f_n \rightarrow cf$
>
> where $c$ is any constant, the convergence being uniform in each case. Hence $f+g \in \mathcal{B}, fg \in \mathcal{B}, cf \in \mathcal{B}$, so that $\mathcal{B}$ is an algebra.
>
> By theorem 2.27, $\mathcal{B}$ is uniformly closed.
>
> Theorem 2.27:
> If $X$ is a metric space, and $E \subset X$ then:
>
> - $\bar{E}$ is closed
> - $E = \bar{E}$ iif E is closed
> - $\bar{E} \subset F$ for every closed set $F \subset X$ s.t. $E \subset F$

Comment: This is just the fact that $\overline{A}=A$, plus the fact that the algebraic properties are preserved through limits.

Comment: You should provide more details on how the proof is carried out in the book. Most of us don't have a copy of PoMA in our hand now.

Comment: For @AloizioMacedo, if we speak about $\mathcal{A} \cup \mathcal{B}$, then I'm ok, but if I understood well, $\mathcal{B}$ only contains the limits, right?

Comment: @yarmenti But $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{B}$, since constant sequences of functions have limits equal to themselves.